# How to copy files in specific location within multiple folders to a shared drive using windows command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I need to copy several backup files to a shared folder

The Source to copy from looks like this below (there is other files inbetween but are not interested in copying them

```
C:\BackupLocation\BCK1\Logs\myLog1.log
C:\BackupLocation\BCK1\Logs\myLog2.log
C:\BackupLocation\BCK1\Logs\myLog3.log

C:\BackupLocation\BCK2\Logs\myLog1.log
C:\BackupLocation\BCK2\Logs\myLog2.log
C:\BackupLocation\BCK2\Logs\myLog3.log

C:\BackupLocation\BCK3\Logs\myLog1.log
C:\BackupLocation\BCK3\Logs\myLog2.log
```

I need to be able to copy any log file with the words "myLog" in the file name.

I thought about doing a For look do get the directory and then using robocopy to copy the files to my shared location

```
FOR /d /r %ROOT_SRC_BACKUP_LOCATION% %%G in (*logs*) DO (
 Pushd %%G

 Robocopy %%G "mybackup location directory" *mylog* /S

 Popd )
```

But the problem is that the logs directory detects other logs directory... for example I have another logs directory in here

```
C:\BackupLocation\BCK3\server\Logs\IDontCareAboutTheLogsIntheServerDirectory.log
```

What is the most effective way to copy all the myLog's in the `C:\BackupLocation\BCKXX\Logs\` folder?

Comment: Not sure the question has all the info but all you seem to need is omitting the `/s` switch and the entire required code would be `robocopy "%ROOT_SRC_BACKUP_LOCATION%" "mybackup location directory" *mylog*` without the `for` loop.

Comment: @wOxxOm  I made mistakes earlier in my answer - just saying that your code will copy files from the single folder `"%ROOT_SRC_BACKUP_LOCATION%"` and there aren't any of the target files in that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this:

```
 @echo off
 Pushd "C:\BackupLocation"
    for /d %%a in (bck*) do (
       if exist "%%a\logs\" Robocopy "%%a\logs" "d:\mybackup location directory\%%a\logs" "*mylog*.log"
    )
 Popd
```

Comment: If I got it right, the source dir. for `robocopy` should be `"%%a\Logs"` rather than `"%%a"`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @aschipfl  The working folder has been changed and robocopy will use a relative path to the working directory.  That's the theory and I haven't tested it to see what happens in practice.

Comment: Since you're using `/S` for `robocopy`, there is a risk of copying files from wrong locations...

Comment: @aschipfl    I can see you are right that there are folders that do need to be excluded.  I added an exclusion for any folder called `server` as that is all the information he's provided.  A problem is that the exclusion is not recursive.

Comment: @aschipfl  You were absolutely right all along, and I had misread the question.  Thanks for bringing that up as I would never have realised.  Mea culpa.